# create hyperlink in sms in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms

Is it possible to create a hyperlink in an sms in an iPhone?

For example, if I want the word 'foo' hyperlinked in HTML then I'll write `<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>` in a normal situation.

If I want to have a certain word in my sms to be hyperlinked to something, is there any way I can do this? Like "I have a `<a href="http://foo.com">surprise</a>` for you" and the receiver taps on the hyperlinked word 'surprise' which will take the user to the destined page.

Any suggestions as to how this can be done? Examples and samples welcome!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I thought that was something that the iPhone did automatically for any text that could be matched as a URL

Comment: But what he wants to do is mask the URL. So basically the world "surprise" would go to http://google.com/

Comment: yup, that's what i wanted to do - mask the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this due to privacy issues. Apple thinks that giving you this ability would allow you to link users to malware and such. Sorry!

Comment: This has nothing to do with apple - it is just not supported on other phones. Even if apple would allow or encourage it for text messages between iphones, these messages would be totally useless when send to other phones.

Comment: How do service/appointment reminder software do this then? Look at apptoto.com (how does it work step 4). It shows a message with hyperlink behind 'Your appointment details'. How does that work? I am not promoting their site but using it as reference.

Comment: @Toastor: I actually got a hyperlink in an iPhone text message. Two words were underlined. When I tapped them, it opened a Wikipedia page. The sender (a family member) said she had not done anything to create it.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot use html tags in sms / text messages. All you can do is insert the URL without the tag. It then depends on the receivers device whether the URL is presented to the user as link or as plain text.

Answer (score 4):

I experimented with exactly this just yesterday. It seems you can't include a nicely formatted hyperlink, unfortunately. I hope to be proven wrong by somebody else, though :-)

However, as you've probably seen yourself, iPhone is able to recognize an URL and you can tap on it to open the URL in Safari (or tap the disclosure button next the message to get more options on what to do with the URL). As far as I can tell the only thing you can do is format your SMS accordingly: "*I have a surprise for you: http://foo.com*" even though that might spoil the surprise ;-)

Answer (score 2):

i don't think it's possible to create hyperlinks in SMS.

The only way is to send an URL, and the iPhone will convert it to a link...

Answer (score 2):

Use a tiny url from [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com). 
It doesn't allow you to do exactly what you are wanting but it at least can be used to cover up the long link. 
This is the closest thing I figure out to do. I was wanting to use the "

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do this. However you could use tinyurl and format it like this
`http://whateverYouWantToSay@tinyurl.com`
Web browsers usually ignore anything before an `@` therefore you could effectively hide the actual site being linked to, as long as your friend does not know that.

What actually happens is the data before the `@` is submitted to the web site in the form `username:password`. However it must be a site that requires authentication to access, or the site will normally just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps, I've noticed that a custom hyperlink is possible on the OS X Messages app, but they have to be copied and pasted. To replicate this right click on a hyperlink in your browser and hit copy link. Then paste into Messages.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh this is possible here is a screenshot of an example - I copied a link from email and pasted in a new SMS - though it appears you cannot type html to create a link....[image]