# use custom link inside SMS with Twillio and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, hyperlink, sms

I am using the Twillio Ruby gem to send sms within my application. When building my message body I have been and am using the rails 'url_helpers' to build my links like so:

```
message += " #{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.vendor_auction_url(@auction)}"
```

I have no issue there. What I am not sure of is if I can customize the text for the link similar to an html link such as:

```
<%= link_to 'HERE', appointment_url(@appointment) %>
```

I know I can't use that same erb/html syntax. Just hoping to accomplish the same effect in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use html tags in sms / text messages. All you can do is insert the URL without the tag. It then depends on the receivers device whether the URL is presented to the user as link or as plain text. Also referenced here:
[create hyperlink in sms in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582223/create-hyperlink-in-sms-in-iphone)